# Pass array value as parameter to URL in MEAN stack app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm working in a MEAN app, in which I want to pass an array value to url and fetch values from mongodb. Actually it's a lat and lng. My url should look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/search?type=latlng&value=[0.123, 0.456]
```

And have to fetch data related to that lat lng. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass literal array objects in the URL like you propose. There are workarounds however. You must either separate the data into `{key}={value}` pairs within the URL, or use a POST request.

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/search?type=latlng&lat=0.123&lng=0.456
     http://localhost:8080/search?type=latlng&coords[]=0.123&coords[]=0.456

POST: http://localhost:8080/search 
      data: { type: 'latlng', value: [0.123, 0.456] }
```